# LED part with 2.5 V and 140 mA replacement

Tags: led, components

I have an LED lamp consisting of 75 LEDs and an LED driver.

Five of the SMD LEDs broke and I'm trying to find replacements. The original manufacturer went out of business.

The LED driver is a constant current 700 mA version.

The construction is of 5 modules in series.
Every module consists of 15 LEDs wired as 3 sub-modules in series. Each one of the 3 sub-modules consists of 5 LEDs in parallel.

I hope this schematic can help a little (ignore the LED part names, I didn't know how to remove those)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRhv8j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now one of the sub-modules doesn't light anymore and after a while the lamp begins to flicker (not sure if it is a short or some other fault, but some of the LEDs had a black dot and some light charring around one of them). I want to find replacement LEDs to solder in place.

Each one of the modules has a 7.5 V drop, the sub-modules have a 2.5 V drop.
If constant current means what I think it means then I am looking for a 2.5 V LED dissipating 140 mA. I can not find such an LED on Mouser or some other electronics sites.

What are my options in terms of LEDs? Solder more 2.5 V LEDs in parallel that use fewer amps?

I tried to solder together three 10 Ω resistors in parallel and replaced it, which made the lamp seem fine.

But if my math is right that's well over 500 mW per resistor to dissipate in heat, and I just had cheap carbon through-hole ones which are probably rated for 1/4 W at most. They did not smolder after an hour but were well on their way to charring.

Comment: There is *replacement with similar light output* and with similar *forward voltage* / "voltage drop". The interconnection shown is - exactly opposite to how I'd do it.

Comment: LEDs are fairly generic, so you can go through the digikey catalog and find another LED with a compatible footprint and a current rating >140mA and solder in place of the dead ones. If you do this it is probably a good idea to change all the parallel diodes, not just the burned ones (since they're probably all damaged if one is burned).

Comment: @user1850479 so if I solder in something with > 140mA, but with a larger forward voltage then as long as the voltage sum of all modules is still within the range of the constant current supply I will be fine? So, will it pretty much "auto-balance"?

Comment: If the forward voltage is different you'd have to change all 5 of the parallel diodes to keep current balanced, but realistically if one burned they're all dead. Assuming you change them all together the forward voltage is irrelevant.

Comment: (identical between parallels) *forward voltage is irrelevant* until the voltage of the whole shebang exceeds the driver's max voltage.

Comment: Alright, I ordered some mostly fitting replacements. The modules are behind a diffuser, so I hope the difference isn't too visible.
I will post an answer if it worked, or post it as an edit in the question if there's an answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up ordering Everstar SMD LED ESS-5730WWDT-R80-WR which worked out great.

As the name implies it has a 5730 package, which didn't match the 2835 of the lamp. But some bodge wiring took care of that.

The data sheet for that LED shows a forward current of 150mA.

After replacing a full submodule row (so 5 parallel LEDS) the lamp worked flicker free again and the difference is barely visible.

I was confused about the constant current configuration of the circuit because I previously only used LEDs with integrated drivers like WS2811.